# Compare output of program to correct program using bash script, without using text files

Tags: bash, scripting

I've been trying to compare the output of a program to known correct output by using a bash script without piping the output of the program to a file and then using diff on the output file and a correct output file.

I've tried setting the variables to the output and correct output and I believe it's been successful but I can't get the string comparison to work correctly. I may be wrong about the variable setting so it could be that.

What I've been writing:

```
TEST=`./convert testdata.txt < somesampledata.txt`
CORRECT="some correct output"
if [ "$TEST"!="$CORRECT" ];
then
  echo "failed"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>if [ "$TEST!"!="$CORRECT" ];</del>

<del>Looks like you have an extra `!` in `$TEST!`.</del>

#### This works for me...

```
$ echo "foobar" > /tmp/test; TEST=`tail -n1 < /tmp/test`; CORRECT="foobar"; if [ "$TEST" != "$CORRECT" ]; then echo "failed"; fi
$
```

#### This fails for me...

```
$ echo "barfoo" > /tmp/test; TEST=`tail -n1 < /tmp/test`; CORRECT="foobar"; if [ "$TEST" != "$CORRECT" ]; then echo "failed"; fi
failed
```

Comment: Oops, that was an accident. Problem still persists though.

Comment: @Doug As you can see from my updated answer, this works for me.  I would `echo $TEST` to make sure that what you think your `convert` program is outputting, really *is* outputting that.

Comment: I believe you're correct as I just confirmed that string comparison is working. I think there's a newline in the output that I'm not checking...

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was using an incorrect string for my correct output, so it always failed.

correction:

```
TEST=`./convert testdata.txt < BothKnownZero.txt`
CORRECT=$'Enter original quantity, original units, new units\n0.0000 miles equals 0.0000 feet'
echo $TEST
echo $CORRECT
if [ "$TEST" != "$CORRECT" ]
then
    echo "failed "
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `zsh` available you can use the `=(cmd)` construct, it saves the output of `cmd` to a temporary file which is deleted when the command returns:

```
if ! diff -q known_good =(cmd); then
  # do something if they differ
fi
```